# X- Editable Undefine in number type

Tags: javascript, php, x-editable

I using x editable. but i want input just number only, and min is 0. max is 100 but i got like this.

```
http://localhost/bismillah/livetableedit/process.php?id=1&data=undefined&key=name
```

undefine in data.

here my code.

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        if($i%2==0) $class = 'even'; else $class = 'odd';

                        echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">
                                <td>'.$no.'</td>
                                <td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name" data-type="number" min="0" max="100">'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
                                <td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="details">'.$fetch['details'].'</td>
                                <td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="status">'.$fetch['status'].'</td>
                            </tr>'; 
                        $no++;                      
                    }
```

and this is my javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('.xedit').editable();     
    $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
        var key = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
        var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
        var y = $('.input-sm').val();
        var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().text(y);



        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&key="+key,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(s){
                if(s == 'status'){
                $(z).html(y);}
                if(s == 'error') {
                alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
            }
        });
    });
```

});

i trying change code like this

```
<a href="#" class="xedit" data-type="number" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name">'.$fetch['name'].'</a>
```

but same problem, any idea?

note: i got this from here

```
http://www.jqueryajaxphp.com/live-table-edit-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-twitter-bootstrap/
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your process.php is correct, you just need to change the key to "key=“number"